# ¿Como comparar fechas en SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo el siguientge probelma:

Quiero mostrar un registro que realizo un tecnico de pruebas a una unidad, a esa misma unidad, un tecnico de diagnostico le hace un registro pero con otra fecha. 
El detalle es que se le pueden hacer varios registros a esa unidad en diferentes fechas.
A lo que quiero llegar es que me muestre el registro que hace pruebas y el que hace diagnostico pero con la fecha mas cercana a la que hace pruebas.

Dejo my query:

```
 select dt.SerialNumber,dt.Model,dt.TestUser,dt.TestTime,dt.FailureOperator+' 
 '+ dt.[Comments/Actions] TestComments,rd.DebugUser,rd.DebugTime,
 rd.DefectDesc+' '+rd.Comment DebugComments

 from [GDJNT422\SQLFF4].[P_REPF5].[dbo].[v_RowData] rd left join
 Debug_Test dt on dt.SerialNumber = rd.Serial

 where dt.SerialNumber is not null and rd.DebugUser is not null
 order by dt.TestTime desc
```

Esto es lo que me arroja el query y marco un ejemplo de lo que quiero.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: con datos de ejemplo seria mas facil entender tu problema

Comment: @gbianchi gracias. ya agregue los datos.

Comment: "quiero llegar es que me muestre el registro que hace pruebas y el que hace diagnostico", ¿cuales son estos registros? no me queda claro viendo los datos.

Comment: @Giovanni tomando en cuenta la descripción que das, en la imagen mostrada, supongo que hay varios registros que cumplen con el criterio que buscas, ya que hay varios dispositivos, sin embargo solo has marcado uno. ¿Por qué has marcado solo uno? O bien la descripción es incorrecta o has olvidado marcar los otros registros en la imagen. Cabe aclarar que lo ideal es publicar los datos como una tabla y no en una imagen. Vendría bien también si pusieras los datos de cada tabla de entrada por separado. Un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según lo que llego a entender de tú escenario, en debug test tienes una serie de items, que estan relacionados con v_rowdata de 1 a varios, porque un elemento de debugtest puede tener varias entradas en row_data y lo que quieres, es que cada elemento solo tenga una entrada que sea de fecha mayor pero la primera.

Tu escenario:

```
CREATE TABLE V_ROWDATA
(SERIAL     VARCHAR(100), 
 DEBUGTIME  DATETIME2, 
 DEBUGUSER  VARCHAR(100), 
 DEFECTDESC VARCHAR(100), 
 COMMENT    VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE DEBUG_TEST
(SERIALNUMBER       VARCHAR(100), 
 MODEL              VARCHAR(100), 
 TESTUSER           INT, 
 TESTTIME           DATETIME2, 
 FAILUREOPERATOR    VARCHAR(100), 
 [COMMENTS/ACTIONS] VARCHAR(100)
);
GO
INSERT INTO V_ROWDATA (SERIAL, DEBUGTIME, DEBUGUSER, DEFECTDESC, COMMENT)
VALUES
('SUB0765G08FY','20200116 23:05','GDIJEPEN (JESUS)','CABLE DAÑADO','EQUIPO'),
('SUB079GG0071','20200116 21:37','GDICOVA (OSCAR)' ,'BAD ASSEMBLY','RETEST'),
('SUB079GG0071','20200117 11:37','GDJALGON (ALEJ)' ,'FALSE CALL'  ,'PARSER');
GO
INSERT INTO DEBUG_TEST (SERIALNUMBER, MODEL, TESTUSER, TESTTIME, FAILUREOPERATOR,     [COMMENTS/ACTIONS])
VALUES
('SUB0765G08FY','ATLANTIS' ,913477,'20200116 21:37','Falla     comunicacion','172.17.116.37'),
('SUB079GG0071','DISCOVERY',913477,'20200116 21:36','Memoria ram mal insertada' ,'');
GO
```

Una de las posibles soluciones, es utiliar LAG/LEAD para obtener el siguiente resultado, pero como es necesario disponer de Sql server 2012 y no mencionas cual es tú motor, voy a darte otra opción, que es utilizar row_number para numerar las filas.

```
;WITH Debug
AS (SELECT dt.SerialNumber
    , dt.Model
    , dt.TestUser
    , dt.TestTime
    , dt.FailureOperator + '' + dt.[Comments/Actions] TestComments
    FROM 
    Debug_Test dt
    WHERE dt.SerialNumber IS NOT NULL),
rowData
AS (SELECT rd.DebugUser
    , rd.DebugTime
    , rd.DefectDesc + ' ' + rd.Comment DebugComments
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY rd.Serial
    ORDER BY rd.debugTime) AS row
    , Debug.SerialNumber
    , Debug.Model
    , Debug.TestUser
    , Debug.TestTime
    , Debug.TestComments 
        FROM v_RowData rd LEFT JOIN Debug ON rd.SERIAL=Debug.SERIALNUMBER 
    WHERE rd.DebugUser IS NOT NULL 
    AND rd.DEBUGTIME>Debug.TESTTIME)
SELECT rowData.DebugUser
 , rowData.DebugTime
 , rowData.DebugComments
 , rowData.SerialNumber
 , rowData.Model
 , rowData.TestUser
 , rowData.TestTime
 , rowData.TestComments 
 FROM rowData WHERE row=1;
```

En la primera tabla de expresión común recogemos, los registros de debug_Test
En la segunda tabla de expresión común mezclamos estos con row_data pero de row-data solo cogemos los que tengan una fecha mayor que la que tiene debug.
Además añadimos la numeración de los registros, por tanto a la salida de este conjunto tendrémos que el que disponga de row un 1 será el primero.

Te dejo un par de enlaces por si tienes dudas con las tablas de expresión común y con el funcionamiento de row_number

[Tablas de expresión común](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2018/12/18/with-cte-tablas-de-expresion-comun-1/)

[Row Number](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/11/11/row-number-numerar-filas/)

Comment: Muchas gracias. tengo el SQL 18. y creo que con el LAG/LEAD puede funcionar.

Comment: Hola Giovanni: El Sql 18 es la herramienta de administración, no el motor en si. El motor lo puedes averiguar con Select @@version

Comment: la version es: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)   Sep 24 2019 13:48:23   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763:

Comment: Prueba la query con Row_number, y si luego te parece oportuno, cambiarla por lag/lead, puedes echarle un ojo a este artículo. https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2018/09/11/lag-y-lead-siguiente-y-anterior/

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo intente con el `Row_Number` pero al final me arroja un error que no se porque lo hace.

Este es el Query:

```
  declare @DebugTest as table(
  SerialNumber varchar(20),
  Model varchar(30),
  TestUser int,
  TestTime datetime,
  TestComments varchar(max)
  );

  declare @Debug as table(
  SerialNumber varchar(30),
  DebugUser varchar(30),
  DebugTime datetime,
  DebugComments varchar(max)
  )

  insert into @DebugTest
  select dt.SerialNumber,dt.Model,dt.TestUser,dt.TestTime,dt.FailureOperator+' '+ dt. 
  [Comments/Actions] TestComments

  from Debug_Test dt

  order by dt.TestTime desc

  insert into @Debug
  select rd.Serial,rd.DebugUser,rd.DebugTime,rd.DefectDesc+' '+rd.Comment 
  DebugComments

  from [GDJNT422\SQLFF4].[P_REPF5].[dbo].[v_RowData] rd 

  order by rd.DebugTime desc;

  with DebugTest as (
  select dt.SerialNumber, dt.Model,dt.TestUser,dt.TestTime,dt.FailureOperator+' '+dt. 
  [Comments/Actions] TestComments
  from Debug_Test dt 
  ),
  result as (
  select d.DebugUser,d.DebugTime,d.DebugComments,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by 
  d.SerialNumber order by d.DebugTime desc) as row,
  dt.SerialNumber,dt.Model,dt.TestUser,dt.TestTime,dt.TestComments
  from @Debug d left join
  @DebugTest dt on dt.SerialNumber = d.SerialNumber
  )
  select 
  r.SerialNumber,r.Model,r.TestUser,r.TestTime,r.TestComments,r.DebugUser,
  r.DebugTime,r.DebugComments
  from result r
  where r.row = 1 
  order by r.TestTime desc
```

El error que arroja es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La version de SQL que estoy utilizando es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El error te dice que no coge el contenido de la información que estas intentando asignar a la columna de la tabla temporal. Cambia ese DebugUser varchar(30) , por un varchar(max) o por el tamaño que necesite esa columna, ya que con 30 caracteres no es suficiente.

Comment: @Javifer2 gracias.

Comment: Deberias anexar nueva informacion a la pregunta, no generarla como una respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Considero que la opcion mas performante es "Cross Apply" (o "Outer Apply", si aun quieres ver Pruebas que no hayan tenido "Diagnosticos" previos)

A modo conceptual digamos que es una "Tabla basada en una tabla superior", teniendo una consulta que genera la "Tabla Base" (digamos), como por ejemplo:

```
SELECT Sector, Fecha, Prueba
FROM Pruebas
```

Podemos añadir "El diagnostico mas cercano del sector" de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT Sector, Fecha, Prueba, UltDiag.Fecha, Comentario
FROM Pruebas
CROSS APPLY(
   SELECT TOP 1 [Diagnostico.]Fecha, [Diagnostico.]Comentario
   FROM Diagnostico
   WHERE [Diagnostico.]Sector = Pruebas.Sector
     AND [Diagnostico.]Fecha <= Pruebas.Fecha
   ORDER BY [Diagnostico.]Fecha DESC
) UltDiag
```

CROSS APPLY puede verse como un JOIN cualquiera pero con la capacidad de embeber atributos de las "tablas superiores" (en este caso "Pruebas.Sector" y "Pruebas.Fecha"), generará el producto cartesiano de cada registro que devuelva (Por eso el "TOP 1") por cada registro de la consulta externa.

Es en la amplia mayoría de los casos mas eficiente que utilizar funciones agregadas en ventana como ROW_NUMBER, o FIRST_VALUE.

El uso de tablas de expresión comunes es absolutamente innecesario en prácticamente todos los casos, meramente es un alias de la estructura lógica de una consulta, como una "vista temporal", puede ayudarte en el desarrollo de consultas largas y complejas.

Como ultima aclaración, no es posible embeber agregaciones de la tabla superior, por ejemplo no podría hacer lo siguiente:

```
SELECT Sector, MAX(Pruebas.Fecha) AS PruFecha, Max(Prueba), Max(UltDiag.Fecha), Max(Comentario)
FROM Pruebas
CROSS APPLY(
   SELECT TOP 1 Fecha, Comentario
   FROM Diagnostico
   WHERE Sector = Pruebas.Sector
     AND Fecha <= Max(Pruebas.Fecha) --Ni "PruFecha" (no funcionan alias, pero si columnas computadas)
   ORDER BY Fecha DESC
) UltDiag
GROUP BY Sector
```

Deberas crear una subconsulta que arroje la agregación (con o sin tablas de expresión común), y luego hacer el join con APPLY, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT Sector, MFecha, Fecha, Comentario
FROM (SELECT Sector, MAX(Fecha) as MFecha
   FROM Pruebas
) Pruebas_Agregadas
CROSS APPLY(
   SELECT TOP 1 Fecha, Comentario
   FROM Diagnostico
   WHERE Sector = Pruebas_Agregadas.Sector
     AND Fecha <= Pruebas_Agregadas.MFecha
   ORDER BY Fecha DESC
) UltDiag
```

Espero que disculpes el no utilizar tu código, en pos de la simplificación explicativa. Traducido a tu consulta seria:

```
SELECT dt.SerialNumber,
   dt.Model,
   dt.TestUser,
   dt.TestTime,
   TestComments = dt.FailureOperator+' '+ dt.[Comments/Actions],
   rd.DebugUser,
   rd.DebugTime,
   DebugComments = rd.DefectDesc+' '+rd.Comment 
FROM Debug_Test dt 
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT TOP 1 DebugUser,
      DebugTime,
      DefectDesc,
      Comment
   FROM  [GDJNT422\SQLFF4].[P_REPF5].[dbo].[v_RowData] 
   WHERE Serial = dt.SerialNumber
      AND DebugUser IS Not null
      AND DebugTime <= dt.TestTime
   ORDER BY DebugTime desc --Tambien, y totalmente ineficiente, podria ser "ORDER BY (DebugTime - TestTime) DESC" Comentando el "AND DebugTime <= dt.TestTime" si "El mas cercano" puede ser en el futuro.
) rd
WHERE dt.SerialNumber IS Not null
```