# ¿Como sacar el valor de una columna tomando el valor asociado a otra columna agregada?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estoy calculando distancias entre un punto con sus colindantes par poder sacar el punto más cercano. El problema surge cuando al agregar por distancia mínima, tengo que quedarme con el valor identificativo del punto colindante más cercano, ya que necesito una función de agregación para quedarme con el identificador de dicho registro con la distancia mínima. Pongo un ejemplo para clarificarlo:

Supongamos que tengo esta tabla

```
    A   B   C       D
0   x   a   1       w
1   y   b   10      v
2   x   a   100     v
3   y   b   1000    w
```

Lo que quiero es agregar por las columnas **A** y **B** y mantener el valor de la columna **D** asociado al valor mínimo de la columna **C**.

El resultado seria el siguiente;

```
    A   B   C       D
0   x   a   1       w
1   y   b   10      v
```

He encontrado un post donde explican como hacerlo en pandas, pero necesito hacerlo en SQL. Link al post:
[Post de como donde se soluciona mi problema en Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47889261/how-to-aggregate-a-column-by-a-value-on-another-column)

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: La pregunta está escrita en un idioma diferente al idioma oficial de este sitio, que es el español.

Comment: El título es parte de la pregunta :)

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon lo que has intentado

Comment: Bienvenido, es demasiado importante agregar lo que intentaste o investigaste, revisar [ask], saludos.

Comment: De acuerdo, soy un nuevo en el sitio, gracias por las aclaraciones. He editado la pregunta, espero que ahora haya mejorado. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una solución, aunque no necesariamente la mas eficiente, seria el uso de la función agregada en ventana ROW_NUMBER, de la siguiente forma:

```
Select A,B,C,D
From (
Select A,B,C,D, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A, B ORDER BY C) AS RN
From tabla
) AS Tabla_RN
Where RN = 1
```

Las funciones agregadas en ventana generan una columna computada posterior a los resultados de una consulta, y por tanto no pueden utilizarse como filtros. Por eso la utilizo dentro de una subconsulta.

Las columnas agregadas en ventana (también denominadas "agregaciones analíticas") se distinguen por la clausula OVER la cual contiene parámetros de ejecución de la función analítica, en este caso Solicitamos que "trate independientemente" (Particiones) los tramos en los que los valores de "A" y "B" difieran (la misma diferenciación que hace el Group By), y que utilice como "el orden de procesamiento" lo que le brinde la columna C. Dado que ROW_NUMBER esencialmente cuenta seriamente, este parámetro (el "ORDER BY") es obligatorio.

Prácticamente todas las funciones agregadas pueden utilizarse en su versión analítica independientemente del motor de base de datos.
Existen otros parámetros de la clausula OVER que no vienen al caso, como los que definen la "limitación de la ventana".

Las funciones analíticas tienen otras limitaciones que no vienen al caso, ademas de no poderse filtrar por ellas, como es la imposibilidad de su uso de forma anidada o dentro de funciones agregadas. Sin embargo pueden tener como parámetros columnas computadas tanto como agregadas.

Comment: Si te preocupa la eficiencia, hace un tiempo hice una explicación del uso del "Apply", originalmente en SQL Server, pero debería ser idéntico en Postgre e igualmente mas eficiente que el row_number: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/428300/74003